# how hashmap object reference change

Tags: java, hashmap

Trying to check how hashmap works

```
public class hashmapcheck {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Person abhishek = new Person("abhishek");
    Map<Person,String> mapCheck = new HashMap<Person,String>();
    mapCheck.put(abhishek,"ancd");
    abhishek.setName("defg");
    System.out.println(mapCheck.get(abhishek));  //line which i try to undertand
}
```

}

```
public class Person {
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

String name;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Person person = (Person) o;

    return name != null ? name.equals(person.name) : person.name == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

}

if equals and hashcode is not overriden  for person class it print ancd,  but when i override it it will print null. 
what i thought when i store objectin hashmap it will store reference of that hashmap what is going wrong

Comment: It's not clear what question you're asking. What are you expecting or trying to achieve?

Comment: Just trying tho study how hashmap and objects hashcode behave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`abhishek.setName("defg")` is mutating a key of your `HashMap` (a `Person` instance) after you added it to the `HashMap`.

This causes the `hashCode()` of that key to change, so the `get()` method fails to locate it according to the new `hashCode()` (since it was placed in a bin that matches the original `hashCode()`.

You are misusing the `HashMap` class. Keys should not be mutated after being added to the `HashMap` (at least properties that affect the outcome of `hashCode` and `equals` should not be mutated).

As for the behavior when not overriding `equals` and `hashCode`, in this case `equals` asnd `hashCode` do not depend on the value of `name`, so changing the `name` makes no difference. In that case, the default implementation guarantees that your key can be found in the `HashMap` if you are searching for the exact same `Person` instance you put into the `Map`.

Comment: So why does not it changed  till the time i override hashcode function in person object .

Comment: To add to the answer: from the documentation of the Map interface: *Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.*

Comment: @abhishekvashistha I added an explanation of that.

Comment: Thanks Eran , it's lot of help , have worked on java for some time but missing some concepts , just trying to play around as much as i can . One more thing hashmap has it own hash function to get hashcodeof the object then why it does not failed in first case .